# Write BsonDocument into MongoDB Spark Scala

Tags: mongodb, scala, apache-spark

I want to save the data into MongoDB while streaming it from Twitter. Each RDD in a DStream holds Array[String] with values, so I set up the keys for these values and wrapped them into org.bson.document. When I try to write Seq of Documents into MongoDB I get such an exception:

```
ERROR Executor: Exception in task 1.0 in stage 8.0 (TID 9)
java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: clusterListener can not be null
```

I used Spark MongoDB connector, so here are the dependencies in my build.sbt file:

```
val sparkVersion = "2.2.0"

libraryDependencies ++= Seq(
  "org.apache.kafka" %% "kafka" % "1.1.0",
  "org.apache.bahir" %% "spark-streaming-twitter" % sparkVersion,
  "org.apache.spark" %% "spark-core" % sparkVersion,
  "org.apache.spark" %% "spark-streaming" % sparkVersion,
  "org.apache.spark" %% "spark-sql" % sparkVersion,
  "org.apache.spark" %% "spark-streaming-kafka-0-10" % sparkVersion,
  "com.typesafe" % "config" % "1.3.0",
  "org.twitter4j" % "twitter4j-core" % "4.0.6",
  "org.twitter4j" % "twitter4j-stream" % "4.0.6",
  "com.twitter" %% "bijection-avro" % "0.9.6",
  "org.mongodb.spark" %% "mongo-spark-connector" % "2.2.2",
  "org.mongodb.scala" %% "mongo-scala-driver" % "2.2.0",
  "org.json4s" %% "json4s-native" % "3.5.3"
)
```

Also, I used MongoDB docker image in my docker-compose file:

```
version: '3.3'
services:
  kafka:
      image: spotify/kafka
      ports:
        - "9092:9092"
      environment:
      - ADVERTISED_HOST=localhost
  mongo:
      image: mongo
      restart: always
      environment:
        MONGO_INITDB_ROOT_USERNAME: admin
        MONGO_INITDB_ROOT_PASSWORD: pwd
  mongo-express:
      image: mongo-express
      restart: always
      ports:
        - 8081:8081
      environment:
        ME_CONFIG_MONGODB_ADMINUSERNAME: admin
        ME_CONFIG_MONGODB_ADMINPASSWORD: pwd
```

This is the code for streaming and writing into the database. WordArrays here is of type DStream[Array[String]]

```
wordsArrays.foreachRDD(rdd => rdd.collect.foreach(
        record => {
          val docs = sparkContext.parallelize(Seq(new Document("tweetId", record(0)),
            new Document("text", record(1)),
            new Document("favoriteCount", record(1)),
            new Document("retweetCount", record(1)),
            new Document("geoLocation", record(1)),
            new Document("language", record(1)),
            new Document("createdAt", record(1))
          ))
          MongoSpark.save(docs)
        }
    ))
```

Comment: The error seems to indicate an authentication problem with the mongo cluster. Is your docker compose file written correctly? I think an environment variable needs to be preceded by a `-`. See https://docs.docker.com/compose/environment-variables/#set-environment-variables-in-containers

Comment: You mean like this? `- MONGO_INITDB_ROOT_USERNAME= admin`

Comment: Yup. Did that fix your issue?

Comment: No. It did not.

Answer (score 0):

Since every element in the DStream an RDD of type Array[String] MongoDB-Spark connector has an implicit method to write the RDDs straight to MongoDB

The Database and Collection are used from SparkConf() that were supplied to it at the time of SparkSession creation

```
wordsArrays.foreachRDD(rdd => rdd.saveToMongoDB())
```

You can additionally pass database, collection and connection URI coonfiguration in a Map to the `WriteConfig` object and use it with the `saveToMongoDB()` helper method as follows(assuming your SparkSession object is called **spark**):

```
import com.mongodb.spark.config._

val writeConfig = WriteConfig(
                             Map("uri":"mongodb://","database":"db_name",
                                 "collection" -> "collectionname",
                                 "writeConcern.w" -> "majority"), 
                                  Some(WriteConfig(spark.sparkContext)
                                )
                             )
wordsArrays.foreachRDD(rdd => rdd.saveToMongoDB(writeConfig))
```